# How to protect iOS bundle files like plist ,image,sqlite,media files

Tags: ios, iphone, bundle

I have created sample hello world project and then added Data.plist file to resource folder.
Now people can easily get the bundle files by unzipping the .ipa file. Is there any ways to protect the Data.plist file that saved in the application bundle of iPhone app?

```
 Encryption is a decent method of scrambling the data but i don't know how to implement encription concept.
```

Do you have any sample code?

[image]

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *arrData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSData *datas = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrData];
    [datas writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

**After extracting IPA file**

[image]

Comment: If the password for decryption is hard-coded, the password can be easily retrieved by de-compiling your binary executable. The key should be protected by Obfuscator.

Comment: @zs2020 any Obfuscator that you would recommend?

Comment: @Ravindhiran, Did you get any solution, I have same problem.

Answer (score 15):

1. encrypt the files on the mac... during deployment:

   FIRST: don't add the files to be encrypted to the target
   e.g. `Encryption-Test.plist`

   THEN add a shell script phase to your xcode project to use `openssl` to encrypt&copy the files.
   e.g.
   `openssl enc -e -aes-256-cbc -pass pass:asdasd
   -in $PROJECT_DIR/test/Encryption-Test.plist 
   -out $TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH/Encryption-Test.enc`
2. add RNCryptor source files from github to your project. This makes decryption of openSSL encrypted AES files really easy. (Thanks rob!) https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor
   (Apple's CCrypt api isn't nice to work with directly)
3. load the data and decrypt it:

e.g.

```
@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Encryption-Test" ofType:@"enc"];
    NSData *passEncryptedData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *pass = @"asdasd";

    NSData *dataDecrypted = [RNOpenSSLDecryptor decryptData:passEncryptedData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:pass error:nil];
    id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:dataDecrypted mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:nil errorDescription:nil];

    assert(plist);
    self.text.text = [plist description];
}

@end
```

---

**added full sample: https://github.com/Daij-Djan/encryptBundleFiles**

Comment: well none AFAICS. It is only a objC wrapper around apple's C API -- the C API sucks IMO and RNCryptor is very lightweight and easy to use

Comment: so you removed Data.plist from the Target!, adapted the in/out paths in shell scripts and now try to read Data.enc?

Comment: there should only be a Data.enc in your bundle in the end

Comment: Thanks Daij-Djan for sharing this very useful sample. Can you let us know how we can generate the password runtime or in more secure way instead of using it hardcoded. I think hardcoded password can be get by the hackers.

Comment: well.. if you want to SHIP encrypted data to the users, you gotta ship the password too (in some way! you can make it hard to find by obscuring it somehow and not writing it there as plain text but ultimately ...... you could maybe also download it from a server ... ) -- this won't be 100% in any case. nothing like this can be.

Comment: If I have to use email Id with which user logs into my application then how I can provide it in run script?

Comment: how would you encrypt data during shipping if you use the future user's credentials?

Comment: you are right. Then how can I protect the password?

Comment: Is this still an issue in iOS 10?

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't know Why not?

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with the above examples with no success and finally found some code that lets you **decrypt an encrypted file (any file in fact) with openssl.** I'm working in the documents folder for this example and I'm not using any shell scripting. Here's how to do it:

1. Encrypt your file in the *Terminal* like so:

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -in questions.plist -out questions.enc
```

2. Add the file(s) to your Xcode project by dragging them to the *Supporting Files* directory
3. Download the *RNCryptor* library [here](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/encryptBundleFiles).
4. Find the *RNCryptor* library in the downloaded project: *encryptBundleFiles-master/test/RNCryptor* and add them into to your Xcode project
5. Import the **RNDecryptor.h** and **RNOpenSSLDecryptor.h** files into your class file, like *ExampleViewController.m* file.
6. Add the code below from where you want to call it, like a certain function.
7. And you're done. You can now use the plist file to for example populate a tableview.

```
// Copy the plist file from the resources folder to the documents folder
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSError *error;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

`NSString *txtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questions.enc"];

    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:txtPath] == NO) {
        NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"questions" ofType:@"enc"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:resourcePath toPath:txtPath error:&error];
    }

    NSString *filePath1 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questions.encr"];

    NSData *passEncryptedData =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath1]  ;
    NSString *pass = @"asdf"; // Insert your password from step 1

    NSData *dataDecrypted = [RNOpenSSLDecryptor decryptData:passEncryptedData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:pass error:&error];

        NSString *appFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"questionsDECRYPTED.plist"]; //The Decrypted file saved here
        [dataDecrypted writeToFile:appFile atomically:YES];`

Comment: I tried this one works nicely. "openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -pass pass:Password1 -in brain.txt -out brain.enc
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -pass pass:Password1 -in brain.enc -out brain2.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Based on Daij-Dan's solution, I created a couple of Swift `String` extensions. Requires [RNCryptor](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/encryptBundleFiles)

They are used like this:

```
//Decrypt a UIImage
let decryptedImage = "encyptedFileNameInBundle".decryptedImage(password: "test")

//Decrypt NSData
let decryptedData = "encyptedDataFileNameInBundle".decryptedData(password: "test")
```

The string is the file name of the resource that has been added to the bundle resources. It assumes the file has an "enc" extension by default, otherwise, pass the file extension with "fileExtension:".

Extension:

```
public extension String {

    func decryptedImage(password: String, fileExtension: String = "enc") -> UIImage? {

         //create encypted file with:
         //openssl aes-256-cbc -in fileName.jpg -out fileName.enc

        if let decryptedData = self.decryptedData(password: password, fileExtension: fileExtension) {
            return UIImage(data: decryptedData)
        }

        return nil
     }

    func decryptedData(password: String, fileExtension: String = "enc") -> Data? {

        //create encypted file with:
        //openssl aes-256-cbc -in fileName.data -out fileName.enc

        if let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self, withExtension: fileExtension) {

            do {
                let encyptedData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
                return try RNOpenSSLDecryptor.decryptData(encyptedData, with: kRNCryptorAES256Settings, password: password)
            } catch {
                print("encryptedImage ERR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a NSKeyedArchiver to create an NSData object from your dictionary (NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:). Then encrypt the NSData with AES and write that to your file.

Reading just the reverse process: first, read the NSData, decrypt it via the method from the mentioned link, then pass the decrypted NSData to NSKeyedUnarchiver (NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:) and you get your dictionary back. That you can use for plist file or as NSDictionary to keep your data safe.

[Example 1](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/475-how-to-use-nskeyedarchiver-to-store-user-settings-on-the-iphone):

[Example 2](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php):

EDIT 2:

```
NSDictionary *Your_NSDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"Obj1", @"Key1",
                           @"Obj2", @"Key2", nil];
//store dictionary
NSMutableData *yourData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:Your_NSDictionary forKey: @"key"];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[yourData writeToFile:@"FilePath" atomically:YES];
```

or

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" 
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableDictionary * rootObject;
rootObject = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[rootObject setValue: data forKey:@"accounts"];
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject: rootObject toFile: path];
```

Comment: this works.. just for the OPs benefit: be aware this takes memory and cpu time ;)

Comment: encrypt the files on the mac... before deployment. Im creating an xcode sample.

Comment: Shared URL for sample implementation.

Comment: arvind i have added my code please edit and post me changed code?  i don't want to write a file document directory or cache directory.

Comment: this doesn't encrypt anything im afraid

Comment: also .. he has bundle files he wants to encrypt which implies this should happen during building. Later you can't modify them

Comment: Here data into the file are getting encrypted, not the file. Once the data encrypted that cannot be viewable in ipa file using some hacking tools.

Comment: again .. sorry I didnt bother.. NSKeyedArchiver doesnt encrypt anything and unpacking it takes 30s more than double clicking a zip